# Difference on Sales based in conditions on another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have below data set, sometimes clients can transfer Amounts from Category A to B, or B to A.
I'm looking to get a new column just when a brand new record is created for Category A just when there is an increase in "TotalPerClient" from previous Month.
for example: value = 20 on July column "BrandNewCat_A" is because there was an increase in "TotalPerCxCateg" A by 70 from previous Month, but also because "TotalPerClient" increased by 20 from previous Month

I used below code to create 2 columns "TotalPerCxCateg" and "TotalPerCx" but now I'm stuck how to create column "BrandNewCateg_A"

```
df['TotalPerCxCateg'] =  df.groupby(['Date','Client', 'Categ'])['Amount'].transform('sum')
df['TotalPerCx'] =  df.groupby(['Date','Client'])['Amount'].transform('sum')
```

```
Client   Date     ProdID    Amount  Categ     
ABC Inc  2022-06      4      50      A           
ABC Inc  2022-06      5      50      B           
ABC Inc  2022-07      4     120      A           
ABC Inc  2022-08      4      40      A           
ABC Inc  2022-08      5      40      B           
ABC Inc  2022-08      6      30      B
```

Desired output

```
Client   Date   ProdID  Amount  Categ TotalPerCxCateg TotalPerCx BrandNewCateg_A
ABC Inc  Jun-22   4      50      A           50             100       0 
ABC Inc  Jun-22   5      50      B           50             100       0
ABC Inc  Jul-22   4     120      A           120            120       20
ABC Inc  Aug-22   4      40      A           40             110       0
ABC Inc  Aug-22   5      40      B           70             110       0
ABC Inc  Aug-22   6      30      B           70             110       0
```

Comment: You can try taking the difference in increments of one: df['test'] = df.groupby(['Client', 'Categ'])['Amount'].diff()   get a column with shifted values: df['shif'] = df.groupby(['Client', 'Categ'])['Amount'].shift()  and then subtract the desired values from it, replacing negative and empty ones with zero: df['resalt'] = (df['test'] - df['shif']).replace(np.nan, 0).clip(lower=0)

Comment: or do it all in one row:  df['resalt'] = df.groupby(['Client', 'Categ'])['Amount'].apply(lambda x: (x.diff() - x.shift()).replace(np.nan, 0).clip(lower=0))